# Xamarin App On iOS Crashes, After Free Provisioning Profile Expired

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I developed an app on Xamarin Studio and deployed it to an iOS device with Free Provisioning.

It worked fine but after a week `the time that Provisioning expires` application crashes on splash screen.

Is there any way to deploy the app free to not crashed after a week version? 
 I want to deploy it to 2 device `1 for mine to test, the other one for my friend` not to publish.

Can anyone help me on this issue?
Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, with a free developer account, the profiles will expire a week from when they are issued.  This is Apple's mechanism to prevent users from distributing apps outside their store.  The free developer account is basically a mechanism to allow developers to test their apps on physical devices, not to run apps medium / long term.

If you want to get a provisioning profile that will last a year, you need to sign up for a paid developer account. If you want apps that don't expire, sign up for a paid account and then publish the app to the App Store.

Short of jailbreaking / other hacks, those are your options.